# MediaWiki pages not working properly

Tags: mediawiki

So recently I've discovered that my mediawiki pages are not functioning correctly. For example, when I edit MediaWiki:ipbreasons-dropdown in an attempt to add extra ban reasons to the dropdown.

The wiki recognizes the edit, even showing a link and diff in RecentChanges, but for some reason the extra dropdown item never shows.

The same is happening with MediaWiki:Grouppage-staff. Obviously this is a huge problem. Anyone know any way I can fix this without re-installing mediawiki?

Comment: what language are you viewing your wiki in?

Comment: Strapping, but I tried vector and monobook and it isn't working in any of them.

Comment: I meant language. Just wanted to make sure you were not viewing your wiki in another language than it's default. Also: Do any messages from the MediaWiki namespace work, or are they all broken? Any error messages in your logs?

Comment: Oh oops, sorry. I read that as "what skin". I'm using the default language, which is set to EN

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a LocalisationCache problem. There are no magic wands for such issues, you need to debug a bit e.g. issuing `wfMessage( 'ipbreasons-dropdown' )` in eval.php. If the message doesn't contain what expected, go over the documentation for [localisation cache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Localisation#Caching) again, it might be something simple like file permissions.